# Is HTTP Shortlived?

Tags: http

I see mainy people class HTTP as a short lived protocol. i.e fire and forget. However with HTTP 1.1 and the use of keepalive connections I wouldnt really say this is the case.

Can any confirm if this is the case or not ?

Answer (score 4):

First, we need a definition.

Long-lived protocols are those for which the connection is intended to remain open indefinitely. (An example of such a protocol is ssh. While an ssh connection can be short, it is meant to be able to idle forever, thus the protocol is long-lived.)

Short-lived protocols are more transactional in nature; a particular action occurs, or series of actions, and then the connection is closed.

By these definitions **HTTP is a short-lived protocol**, even with keep-alive.

The fact that an HTTP connection may remain open for minutes or hours while data is being transferred is irrelevant.

And Keep-Alive is a performance optimization meant to allow a client to make multiple requests of the server over a short period of time. Servers must drop an idle Keep-Alive connection after some time, because they have only a limited amount of resources for holding open ports, and the client doesn't need it to remain open anyway.

Because HTTP cannot remain open and idle forever, and is not designed to do so, it is a short-lived protocol.

Answer (score 1):

It Depends<sup><sub>TM</sub></sup> - some HTTP sessions are a few hundred millionseconds in length, others such as downloading a large resource or executing a slow REST call are a few seconds or minutes in length. Others can be much, much longer due to the use of keepalives.

So no, I would not say that HTTP is exclusively short-lived.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, fire and forget does not mean what you think it means. I highly recommend that you read more about this as it doesn't seem to be on-topic of the question.

On-topic: Yes, keep-alive does permit sending multiple messages within the same TCP connection but usually you shall not assume that a session stays open as long as you want it or need it, due to multiple reasons:

1. Most web servers limit the maximum number of Keep Alive requests sent through a connection, as well as the time spent until a subsequent request is being sent.
2. Raising the limits mentioned as the previous point will make the server more vulnerable to certain types of Denial of Service and Distributed Denial of Service attacks, such as [slowloris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(software)).
3. You need to take into consideration the network design that the server sits behind. For example, many REST services sit behind a load balancer that distributes the workload to multiple servers. It is not mandatory that all requests coming from a keep-alive TCP connection go to the same backend, in which case you are no longer talking about a real connection to the backend server.